# Android Studio "Might Be Null" Warning for URLUtil.isValidUrl() but not for TextUtils.isEmpty()

Tags: android, android-studio, warnings

I was wondering why this is the case:

[image]

Notice that the order of the the two if statements does not change the behavior.

If you have a look at the source code of the two checker functions I don't see any significant difference of the two. So why do I get a warning in the second case only ?

```
public static boolean isEmpty(@Nullable CharSequence str) {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public static boolean isValidUrl(String url) {
    if (url == null || url.length() == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return (isAssetUrl(url) ||
            isResourceUrl(url) ||
            isFileUrl(url) ||
            isAboutUrl(url) ||
            isHttpUrl(url) ||
            isHttpsUrl(url) ||
            isJavaScriptUrl(url) ||
            isContentUrl(url));
}
```

---

**Update**: Solution:

Since the TextUtils.isEmpty() has a @Nullable tag on the parameter the following applies:

> Variables, method parameters and return values marked as @Nullable or
>   @NotNull are treated as nullable (or not-null, respectively) **and used
>   during the analysis to check nullability contracts**, e.g. report
>   possible NullPointerException errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should notice that TextUtils.isEmpty parameter is annotated with @Nullable annotation. UrlUtil.isValidUrl does not have this annotation.

Comment: I also saw that but I thought the @Nullable was supposed to help the callee function not the caller.

Comment: No you were right I guess: Variables, method parameters and return values marked as Nullable or NotNull are treated as nullable (or not-null, respectively) and used during the analysis to check nullability contracts, e.g. report possible NullPointerException errors.